# Accessing MySQL through threads in C++ application on Windows 8

Tags: mysql, multithreading, visual-c++, mysql-connector

My C++ application (being developed in Visual Studio 2012 on x64 Windows) has threads (threadpool based). It needs to access and select/update rows from table(s) in a database. I plan to use MySQL DB for this.

I am trying to find is it safe to use MySQL Connector/C++ for selecting/updating rows of table through threads.

As I can gather from the reference manual below that libmysqlclient library (for MySQL C API) is thread safe:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-threaded-clients.html

But there is no mention of thread safety about MySQL Connector/C++ library (mysqlcppconn-static.lib):
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/index.html

Can someone please help me ?

Thanks in anticipation